# Accessing the Backbone model.save() POST payload in the node-express backend

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I have written a code snippet using backbone which POST's data to the urlRoute .

```
(function(){
    "use strict"
     window.Course = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            title:''
            },
        urlRoot:"courses/"


        });
    var courses = new Course({title:"Sending a Post request to the node-express backend,but how to access this in the backend"});
    courses.save();

})();
```

I have used node.js - express framework in the backend ,i want to know how to retrieve the value of the title attribute using the **app.post('/courses',function(req,res){})** method . 
This is the node.js backend ,The control comes to the app.post method , but just want ot how to the access the model value in the posted data .

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});


app.post('/courses',function(req,res) { 
        console.log('Request successfully recieved');
    console.log("how do i get the posted data here !!");
});
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
    });
```

Comment: it looks incomplete, how exactly you store the models on server side? if you just want to list them on client just create a `Backbone.Collection` and `.add()` models on it, then query on the client, then you could the same thing on server, and keep syncing the collections and models, so it can be same on all clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your request data in req.body (more on that http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body).

In your case you can do like this:

```
app.post('/courses',function(req,res) { 
    console.log(req.body.title);
});
```